Etale fundamental group with universally closed etale morphisms?
The question is somewhat vague, I apologize in advance.
Given a geometric point $\bar x: \operatorname{Spec} \Omega \to X$, the standard definition of étale fundamental group is as the automorphism group of the fiber functor
$$
FEt_X \to \operatorname{Set}, Y/X \mapsto Y_{\bar x}(\Omega).
$$
When $X$ is unibranch one has the following equivalence (see Tag $0$GIY on stacks project):
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\text { finite type, locally constant } \\
\text { sheaves of } \mathbb{Z} \text {-modules on } X_{\text {etale }}
\end{array}\right\} \longleftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\text { finite } \mathbb{Z} \text {-modules } M \text { endowed } \\
\text { with a continuous } \pi_1(X, \bar{x}) \text {-action }
\end{array}\right\}.
$$
When $X$ is not unibranch this fails: for instance, let $C/\mathbb{C}$ be a rational nodal curve, then the locally constant analytic sheaf on $C(\mathbb{C})$ whose monodromy is generated by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$ can be defined algebraically,
and yet this algebrization does not arise from a $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \cong \pi_1(X,\bar x)$-module of finite type.
My question is: can one take instead a different definition to fix this issue?
E.g. maybe one could define $\pi_1'(X,\bar x)$ as the automorphism group of the fiber functor
$$
UCSEt_X \to \operatorname{Set}, Y/X \mapsto Y_{\bar x}(\Omega),
$$
where $UCSEt_X$ denotes the category of universally closed separated étale schemes over $X$, and this might work?
It feels like this should give fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ for $C$ instead of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Yes.
Let me point out that your equivalence is just a consequence of the following more general fact.

Fact: Let $X$ be a connected scheme with geometric point $\overline{x}$ with associated fiber functor $F_{\overline{x}}$. Then,
$F_{\overline{x}}$ defines an equivalence of categories
$$F_{\overline{x}}\colon \mathbf{F\acute{E}t}(X)\xrightarrow{\sim}
 \pi_1^\mathrm{\acute et}(X,\overline{x})\text{-}\mathbf{FinSet}.$$

Here the target of this equivalence is the category finite sets (with the discrete topology) equipped with a continuous action of the pro-finite group $\pi_1^\mathrm{\acute et}(X,\overline{x})$. You would like to enlarge the fundamental group so that one may replace $\mathbf{FinSet}$ with $\mathbf{Set}$, the category of all discrete sets with a continuous action.
This is achieved by Bhatt—Scholze with their introduction of the proétale fundamental group—see [BS, §7]. There they define a category $\mathbf{Cov}_X$ of geometric coverings which are, by definition, étale and partially proper (i.e., is quasi-separated and satisfies the valuative criterion for properness) morphisms $Y\to X$—so quite close to your category $\mathrm{UCS\acute Et}_X$!
They moreover show that (when $X$ is locally topologically Noetherian) the pair $(\mathbf{Cov}_X,F_{\overline{x}})$ is a tame infinite Galois cateogry (in the sense of loc. cit.). This, in particular, implies that $F_{\overline{x}}$ induces an equivalence of categories
$$F_{\overline{x}}\colon\mathbf{Cov}_X\xrightarrow{\sim} \pi_1^{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}(X,\overline{x})\text{-}\mathbf{Set},$$
where $\pi_1^{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}(X,\overline{x}):=\mathrm{Aut}(F_{\overline{x}})$, topologized in an appropriate manner (again see loc. cit.). This group is not, in general, profinite or even prodiscrete! Note moreover that when $X$ is (geometrically) unibranch, they show in Lemma 7.4.10 of loc. cit. that $\pi_1^{\mathrm{\acute et}}(X,\overline{x})\simeq \pi_1^{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}(X,\overline{x})$ so, as you already intuited, this story is only new when $X$ is not geometrically unibranch.
Moreover, they show that the functor
$$\mathbf{Cov}_X\xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbf{Loc}(X_{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}),\quad Y\mapsto \mathrm{Hom}_X(-,Y),$$
is an equivalence. Here $X_{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}$ is the proétale site as in op. cit., whose objects are weakly étale maps $Y\to X$ (i.e., both $Y\to X$ and $\Delta_{Y/X}\colon Y\to Y\times_X Y$ are flat) with jointly surjective morphisms as covers. Moreover, $\mathbf{Loc}(X_{\mathrm{pro\acute et}})$ denotes the category of locally constant sheaves of sets on $X_{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}$.
As a formal consequence of these results, one sees that there is an equivalence of categories
$$\mathbf{Loc}_{\mathbb{Z}}(X_{\mathrm{pro\acute et}})\xrightarrow{\sim}\pi_1^{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}(X,\overline{x})\text{-}\mathbf{Ab},\qquad\qquad(1)$$
where the source is the category of locally constant sheaves of abelian groups on the proétale site of $X$, and the target is the category of (discrete) abelian groups equipped with a continuous action of $\pi_1^{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}(X,\overline{x})$.
This is almost what you wanted, but you didn’t want to the proétale site, you wanted the étale site. But, there is an easy. way to extract this from the above discussion. Namely, let the SGA3 fundamental group of $X$ be the maximal prodiscrete quotient of $\pi_1^{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}(X,\overline{x})$ and denote it $\pi_1^{\mathrm{SGA3}}(X,\overline{x})$. Then, one may show (see [BS, Lemma 7.4.5]) that (1) induces an equivalence of categories
$$\mathbf{Loc}_{\mathbb{Z}}(X_{\mathrm{\acute et}})\xrightarrow{\sim}\pi_1^{\mathrm{SGA3}}(X,\overline{x})\text{-}\mathbf{Ab},$$
thus arriving at your case of interest.
Example: Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $C=\mathbb{P}^1_K/(0\sim \infty)$ be the projective nodal cubic. Then, one can show that (for any geometric point $\overline{c}$) $\pi_1^{\mathrm{pro\acute et}}(C,\overline{c})\simeq \pi_1^\mathrm{SGA3}(C,\overline{c})\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, with the discrete topology. The corresponding SGA3 covering realizing this is $\widetilde{C}\to C$ where $\widetilde{C}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-many copies of $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ which are glued together pole-to-pole. $\blacksquare$
TL;DR: There is an enlargement of the fundamental group that does what you want, the SGA3 fundamental group. It is not quite of the form you guessed, but your guess is quite close to the proétale fundamental group, which has the SGA3 fundamental group as its maximal prodiscrete quotient.
References:
[BS] Bhatt, B. and Scholze, P., 2015. THE PRO-ÉTALE TOPOLOGY FOR SCHEMES. Astérisque, 369, pp.99-201.

Thank you! I realise now universally closed was the wrong thing to do, $\tilde C \to C$ is not even closed: the projection to $C$ of the subset of $\tilde C$ made of one "random" point on each component is infinite and thus not closed.

@Julian Yes, because it's not quasi-compact. Partially proper (as in geometric coverings) are like "proper-qc".

@Julian Sorry that should be read as "proper MINUS quasi-compact".

@Julian If you are satisfied with my answer you can upvote/accept it (to get it off the unanswered list).
